# Navigation bar alignment with logo

Tags: html, css

I would like my navigation bar to span the full width of the screen (there is a patch of white to the left of the nav bar). I would also like the tabs to be centered. Can anyone help me with this? I am a beginner to this so please explain thoroughly. I would also like to put my logo to the left of my nav bar, does anyone know how to put that there and how many pixels to display my logo, thanks.

Here is my html code.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Connection InterFace</title>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Here is my css.

```
body {
  background-color:white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:red;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
  li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  li a:hover {
  background-color:maroon;
}
ul {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}
.active {
  background-color:black;
```

Comment: Using flexbox in css is super flexible in these kind of scenarios .More about flexbox in https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I updated my answer to show a logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space was there because the browser has a default margin and padding. so you remove  the padding by doing a "CSS reset". I just showed a basic way to remove the paddings and margin for everything. Now you can set your own custom padding and margins for whatever you want.

I don't know if you're aware, but I wanted to say that browsers come with there default "User agent" styles. For example the default font size is  16px for most browsers but you can override that like the padding and margin. in your case I believe that the body had a margin of 8px.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color:white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:red;
}
li {
  float: left;

}
  li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  li a:hover {
  background-color:maroon;
}
ul {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}
.active {
  background-color:black;
}
.logo{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20%;
 background: orange;
 padding: 22px 24px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class = "logo"><div >LOGO</div></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a demo of moving around the nav elements to make it more centered by playing around with the `li:nth-child(2) a{
    margin-left: 50px ;
}` .. This is not the best way but It's a good way without changing your HTML set up.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color:white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:red;
}
li {
  float: left;

}
  li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  li a:hover {
  background-color:maroon;
}
li:nth-child(2) a{
 margin-left: 50px ;
}
ul {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}
.active {
  background-color:black;
}
.logo{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20%;
 background: orange;
 padding: 22px 24px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class = "logo"><div >LOGO</div></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I added below how to show an image for the logo I like using background-images because we get to use `background-size: cover;` helpful for displaying images in places.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color:white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:red;
}
li {
  float: left;

}
  li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  li a:hover {
  background-color:maroon;
}
li:nth-child(2) a{
 margin-left: 50px ;
}
ul {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}
.active {
  background-color:black;
}
.logo{
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 width: 20%;
 background: orange;
 /*padding: 22px 24px;*/
}
.logo div{
 background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100/ff66cc/ffffff&text=IMAGE") no-repeat center center ;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 65px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class = "logo"><div></div></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, exactly do place my logo image in?

Comment: Sorry, where do i place my logo image?

Comment: I updated the answer on how to show an image for the logo. I got the image from http://placehold.it/100x100/ff66cc/ffffff&text=IMAGE ..  Using background images is good because I like using `background-size: cover;` You could put your image in the html. just play around with the size.

Comment: Great. I'm glad it helped can you please upvote this answer **and** click the check mark when you get a chance. Welcome to Stack Overflow and good luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of whitespace in the left corner
you can make margin,padding 0

```
body {
  background-color:white;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grvpOE

Add logo to the left,
by adding line-height according to the size of the image

```
li {
  float: left;
  line-height:7.2px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNQbwb